# Getting error when converting string to object id in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection `booking`. In this collection I have a field `user`. There is 24000 rows in this collection. A-present `user` field data type is string. I need to update `user` datatype from `string` to `objectId`. I tried below script but getting error. **Mongo Db version is 3.2.12**

```
> db.booking.find({user: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) {
...     x.user = ObjectId(x.user);
...     db.booking.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {user: x.user}});
... });
2017-09-12T10:05:30.092+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: invalid object id: length :
@(shell):2:14
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:501:1
@(shell):1:1
>
```

**Booking Collection**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58046a49f8f888a80b00002a"), "cabinname" : "Matras-Haus", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-10-17T00:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2016-10-20T00:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "beds" : "2", "dormitory" : "1", "sleeps" : "3", "clubmember" : "1", "status" : "4", "comments" : "", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-10-17T06:06:01Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1), "payment_status" : "1" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58183678d2ae67a404431d5c"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-10-31T23:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2016-11-23T23:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "beds" : "2", "dormitory" : "0", "sleeps" : "2", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "1", "total_price" : "1288", "payon_cabin" : "1288", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "2", "comments" : "", "prepayment_amount" : "0", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-01T06:30:16Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1), "payment_status" : "0" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("581b31f3d2ae674d5f431d5b"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2016-11-07T23:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2016-11-17T23:00:00Z"), "user" : "", "beds" : "3", "dormitory" : "0", "sleeps" : "3", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "1", "total_price" : "840", "payon_cabin" : "840", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "3", "comments" : "", "prepayment_amount" : "0", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-03T12:47:47Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5821af65d2ae67c82154efc5"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-09-05T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2018-01-24T23:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "sleeps" : "2", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "1", "total_price" : "5640", "payon_cabin" : "5630", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "2", "comments" : "", "prepayment_amount" : "21.25", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-08T10:56:37Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("582558d4d2ae679c4d8b4567"), "cabinname" : "2", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-07-31T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2017-08-02T22:00:00Z"), "user" : "57877d23049ac1b819000029", "beds" : "", "dormitory" : "", "sleeps" : "2", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "", "total_price" : "80", "payon_cabin" : "60", "halfboard" : "", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "2", "prepayment_amount" : "20", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-11T05:36:20Z"), "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58352c3cd2ae672341ec89e1"), "cabinname" : "Kemptner Hütte", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-05-31T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2017-06-02T22:00:00Z"), "user" : "", "beds" : "", "dormitory" : "", "sleeps" : "2", "clubmember" : "0", "status" : "", "total_price" : "80", "payon_cabin" : "60", "halfboard" : "", "bed_prefer" : "0", "guests" : "2", "prepayment_amount" : "20", "bookingdate" : ISODate("2016-11-23T05:42:20Z"), "reservation_cancel" : "2", "is_delete" : NumberLong(1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.booking.find({user: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) { 
    x.user = new ObjectId(x.user);
    db.booking.save(x);
});
```

However, your `user` value must be a unique hexadecimal string else this will fail.

Comment: I have added this line but getting the same error. `db.booking.find({user: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) {     var id = new ObjectId(x.user);     db.booking.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {user: x.user}}); });`

Comment: Try this:

`db.booking.find({user: {$exists:true}}).forEach( function(x) { 
 var id = new ObjectId(x.user); 
 db.booking.update({_id: x._id}, {$set: {user: id }}); 
});`

Comment: Applied the same code but still getting same error.

Comment: Can you paste few records from your booking collection here ?

Comment: I have added the booking collection in my question